# Exchange Powershell - Bulk add new SMTP address to all mailbox users

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

Exchange Server 2007

I need to run a command across all mailboxes to insert a new SMTP address to each mailbox. Easy enough to run a `Get-MailContact` to add new addresses if they are all the same format.  Such as `FirstName+"."+.LastName` at the domain.  However, not all SMTP addresses follow this convention.

We have some addresses that are, for example: `john.doe@domain.com`, `jane.l.smith@domain.com` and `jsmith@domain.com`.

I need to keep those existing smtp addresses but add a new smtp address with a new domain and keep the prefix format.  So, I need to add `john.doe@newdomain.com`, `jane.l.smith@newdomain.com`, and `jsmith@newdomain.com` to the those three mailboxes.

I'm just not sure how to scan all the mailboxes for any address that contains `*@domain.com` and add `*@newdomain.com`

What can I do here?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this *should* work, but I haven't tested it, so I would definitely test it against a test environment before destroying your exchange server...

```
$NeedsNew = get-mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object { $_.EmailAddresses -like "*@domain.com"
foreach ( $Mailbox in $NeedsNew ) {
    $EmailAddresses = $Mailbox.EmailAddresses
    $Changed = $false
    foreach ( $Address in $EmailAddresses ) {
        if ( $Address -like "*@domain.com" ) {
            ( $prefix, $oldDomain ) = $Address.AddressString.split("@")
            $EmailAddresses += "{0}@newdomain.com" -f $prefix
            $Changed = $true
        }
    }
    if( $Changed ) {
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mailbox -EmailAddresses $EmailAddresses
    }
}
```